# How to compute this integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How to compute this integral?

$$\int \limits_{C}^{}\frac{z^{a}\,dz}{(z^3+1)^2}$$

Given that $a>0$ and  $ C:= \{z:|z+1|=\frac{1}{2}\}$

so I know that $log(-1) = \pi i $ and $z^a := e^{alog(z)}$

Comment: What do you think you should do? What have you tried?

Comment: If I use the word "residue" does that put you in the right direction?

Comment: I changed the function into $$\frac{z^a z }{z(z^3+1)^2}$$ and using order 2 limit maybe?

Comment: @wendy,      solve $z^3+1=0$ or $z^3=-1=\cos\pi+i\sin \pi$ to find out poles then use residual theorem

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $w=z+1$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(w-1)^a}{(w^3-3w^2+3w)^2}
&=e^{\pi ia}\frac{(1-w)^a}{9w^2\left(1-w+\frac13w^2\right)^2}\\
&=e^{\pi ia}\frac{\left(1-aw+O\left(w^2\right)\right)\left(1+2w+O\left(w^2\right)\right)}{9w^2}\\
&=e^{\pi ia}\left[\frac1{9w^2}+\frac{2-a}{9w}+O(1)\right]
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, the residue at $z=-1$, or $w=0$, is $\frac{2-a}9e^{\pi ia}$. Since that is the only singularity inside the contour, if the contour is counter-clockwise, we get
$$
\int_C\frac{z^a\,\mathrm{d}z}{(z^3+1)^2}=2\pi i\frac{2-a}9e^{\pi ia}
$$